# Google Apps Script (seemingly) hangs (circle icon runs indefinitely) randomly in a loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I didn't do a great job of explaining the problem. The hanging behavior seems to be related to the use of console logging (with either Logger.log or console.log statements). If I comment out the logging statements, the hanging behavior does not occur. So, if I put in a breakpoint, the looping code will stop at the breakpoint one or a few times after clicking Resume and then just hang without getting back to the breakpoint. The number of successful times hitting the breakpoint before the hanging behavior occurs seems to be random. So, it seems that the problem is related to there being console logging in the loop. If I remove the logging statements, the hanging behavior does not occur. Thanks for any suggestions, here.

I have a loop that hangs in the debugger when a breakpoint{s) are set (but seemingly not when there are no breakpoints set). I've tried putting breakpoints in at various locations and then step over the breakpointed statement and then continue execution. Sometimes (randomly) it just never returns to the breakpoint and just runs forever (until timeout). Here's my code. Can anybody see what's going on. Thanks.

```
  function getHikesDataByMonth() {
    var firstHikeMonth = events[1][0].getMonth();
    var thisHikeMonth = firstHikeMonth;
    //var hikesColumn = firstHikeMonth;
    var hikeDate, hikeDay,hikeName, hikeLevel, hikeNameShort; 
    var hikeMonth, newHikeMonth;
    var eventRow = 1;
    var hikeRow = 0;
    var participantNumber = 0;
    var numParticipants;
    var hikeData = [];
    var hikesColumn = [];
    var hikeDate, hikeName, hikeNameShort, hikeLevel;

    Logger.log("events.length " + events.length)
    while (eventRow < events.length) {
      //if (events[eventRow][4].isBlank) { break;}
      if ((!events[eventRow][4].includes("hike") && !events[eventRow][4].includes("Hike") && !events[eventRow][4].includes("HIKE")) || events[eventRow][4].includes("CANCEL")) {
        eventRow += 1;
        continue;
      }
      // found a hike
      console.log("Found Hike: " + events[eventRow][4]);
      hikeName = events[eventRow][4];
      hikeMonth = events[eventRow][0].getMonth() - firstHikeMonth;
      if (hikeMonth > thisHikeMonth - firstHikeMonth) {
        newHikeMonth = true;
        thisHikeMonth = hikeMonth;
      } else {
        newHikeMonth = false;
      }
      hikeLevel = getHikeLevel(hikeName);
      hikeNameShort = getHikeNameShort(hikeName);

      hikeDate = events[eventRow][0];
      hikeDay = weekDayNames[hikeDate.getDay()];

      hikeData.push(hikeDay);
      hikeData.push(hikeDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
      hikeData.push(hikeName)
      hikeData.push(hikeNameShort);
      hikeData.push(hikeLevel);
      hikeData.push("");
      hikeData.push("");
      //hikeRowArray[0] = hikeRow;
      //hikeData[hikeRow] = hikeRow;

      console.log("Getting Participants: " + hikeName)
      while (events[eventRow][4] == hikeName){

        if (events[eventRow][9] != "Paid") {
          eventRow += 1;
          continue;
        }
        
        hikeData.push(events[eventRow][6] + " " + events[eventRow][5]);
        eventRow += 1;
        participantNumber += 1;
      }
      numParticipants = participantNumber
      for (var i = participantNumber+1; i < 30; i++){
        hikeData.push("");
      }
      //Logger.log(hikeParticipants[participantNumber]);
      hikeData.push(numParticipants < 15 ? "Yes" : "No");
      hikeData.push(15 - numParticipants);

      // That's all for that hike - go to next hike
      participantNumber = 0;
      eventRow += 1;
      hikeData.push(hikeData);
      hikesColumn.push(hikeData);
      console.log("Going to next hike at eventRow:" + eventRow)

      if (newHikeMonth) {
        hikesDataByMonth.push(hikesColumn);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi there @AndyFranklin! I get that you set many breakpoints that are ignored by the Apps Script debugger. If my understanding of your question is correct, could you please signal where you have put those breakpoints?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal set of data which causes this behavior?

Comment: Thank you for the update - and someone may have an answer. But to be clear: Are you saying the problem only happens (unpredictably) when you use "Debug" (with certain logging statements), but it never happens when you use "Run" (with those same logging statements)?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that "Stepping over" or "Resuming" after hitting a breakpoint in Debug mode causes the hang only if there are Logging statements in the code. But Running the program with Logging statements causes no hanging behavior and the Logging statements are executing appropriately. This is very strange and it's hard to believe such a basic debugging strategy doesn't work.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this issue yet. When you say «*after hitting a breakpoint in Debug mode*», could you please identify in which lines you put the breakpoints? Also, if the issue is generated on the `console.log()` lines, please change them to [`Logger.log()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging) and see if it helps.